# How efficiently are documents stored on disk?

Tags: rethinkdb

In RethinkDB, how efficiently are documents stored on disk? How does this compare to other databases, like MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, Cassandra? Does RethinkDB use greater, lesser, or equal space to store the same or similar data? This is what I mean by 'efficient'.

Obviously, I imagine that it may be difficult to compare in this way, but I am curious nevertheless. It would be helpful to get a sense of the general disk usage profile of each database, and whether some databases may be more or less efficient with their disk usage than others. In particular, it would be great to get a sense of where RethinkDB stands in this regard.

Comment: You should define "efficient". In modern Cassandra, for example, cell compression is configurable (both algorithm and parameters, so LZ4 or Snappy or similar), but there's a bit of data duplication for cell names and timestamps (potentially), but quantifying efficient should help improve the quality of your answers.

Comment: @JeffJirsa My apologies. I am interested in how much disk space it would take different databases, in comparison to RethinkDB, to store similar data. This is what I meant by 'efficient'.